# Looking for strategy to resolve: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, dependencies, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

I have an issue with the following error: "Could not load file or assembly". The error speaks for itself: Micorsoft.Owin version 2.0.0.0 fails to load in System.Web.Http.Owin. But I want to use Microsoft.Owin 3.0.0.0 and the dll of System.Web.Http.Owin I do reference has version 5.2.2.0 which on its own should work with Microsoft.Owin.

So my question here is who is referencing  Micorsoft.Owin version 2.0.0.0?

And therefore: **How can I find out which assembly is asking for Micorsoft.Owin 2.0.0.0?**

Are there a recommended strategy for such issues?

What I tried to do so far is adding a binding redirect. But this would more be a workaround rather than a nice solution (and it did not work btw.):

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: @Jester: I think it is not a duplicate. I do not ask how to enable assembly bind failure logging though using assembly bind failure logging would be an answer to my question. People how are looking for a strategy for this kind of problems do not yet know that 'assembly bind failure logging' does exist, so they will not search for this words... you see my points?

Comment: Yes they may search for this, and find the link to the other question which answers their question. See my point? ;)

Comment: Duplicates still show up in search, yes. You can try it :)

Comment: I just realized that others will still see the question. So thanks for linking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool `Fuslogvw.exe` to get a log of assembly bindings, in particular what loaded what and where it looked for the assemblies.

It's installed with Visual Studio, but to run it you will need to open a Visual Studio command prompt ([like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and then run

```
fuslogvw
```